# How to update a data everytime a delayedjob is executed in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using DelayedJob for scheduling `report` and sending it to `customer` in rails. The `Customer` can select the report of particular time duration. For example, `customer` can select report from date '05/04/2019' to date '06/04/2019'. `Customer` can also set the `frequency` and `time`.i.e. to run the report daily at some given time. In such case, the `from` and `to` date will get incremented daily. If `frequency` is `monthly`, the dates will update accordingly.

My code is as follows:

`Report#schedule` method:

```
      def schedule
        #send report to customer
      end
      handle_asynchronously :schedule,
        frequency: Proc.new{ |r| r.deliver_frequency },
        run_at: Proc.new { |r| r.next_reschedule_time },


      def deliver_frequency
        if frequency.eql?('daily')
          'daily'
        elsif frequency.eql?('monthly?')
          'monthly'
        end
      end
```

The 'from' date and'to' date is taken from `customer_params`

```
    @customer.params[:from] = params[:from]
    @customer.params[:to] = params[:to]
    @customer.save
```

The above params get saved in `customer` attributes as:

```
    :id => 10167,
    :params => {
        "from" => "05/04/2019",
        "to" => "06/04/2019"
    }
```

This dates are saved in `report_name` which is sent to `customer`.

My question, how to check whether the delayed_job has executed the given task, so that `from` and `to` date can be updated.

What I want to achieve is, everytime the `schedule` method is executed, the dates should get updated according to frequency.
For eg: If the report is scheduled for 'daily', the `from` and `to` date should get updated daily after `schedule` is executed.

Similarily, if frequency is 'monthly' and report is scheduled at date `from: 22/3/2019 to: 22/4/2019`, then on next execution of schedule method, the dates should get updated to `from: 22/4/2019 to: 22/5/2019`

I tried adding `+1` for daily. But this won't work for monthly frequency.

Can anybody guide me how the above can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: if you want to check whether time is updated or not you can simply print it by puts

Comment: no i want to update the date so that report_name can be updated